# Extracting only alphanum and hyphen problem with exclamation

Tags: regex

I am trying to split the string if anything except a-zA-Z0-9- comes. But ! is not getting split.

```
li=re.split('([^a-zA-Z0-9-])+',st)
st="We are at Ignite Solutions! Their email-id is careers@ignitesol.com"
#Output : ['We', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'at', ' ', 'Ignite', ' ', 'Solutions', ' ', 'Their', ' ', 'email-id', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'careers', '@', 'ignitesol', '.', 'com']
```

Why no exclamation symbol is coming after Solutions

Expected output:
    #Output : ['We', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'at', ' ', 'Ignite', ' ', **'Solutions', '!', ' '**, 'Their', ' ', 'email-id', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'careers', '@', 'ignitesol', '.', 'com']

Comment: Try removing the capturing group`[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+`

Comment: Still the same, and spaces got removed from the list now

Comment: You need to put the `+` quantifier inside the group: `([^a-zA-Z0-9-]+)`

Comment: @bobblebubble this is working, but can you explain how ?

Comment: But still there is one problem, after ! sign, the space after that got removed

Comment: If you quantify the group, it always contains just the last match which is one `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]`

Comment: The output now is 

'Solutions', '! ', 'Their', but it should be 'Solutions', '! ', ' ', 'Their',

Comment: And if you use `([^a-zA-Z0-9-])` without any quantifier? (you should get two matches: `!` and space).

Comment: An extra character is coming if I remove the quantifies

'Solutions', '!', '', ' ', 'Their'

Comment: Have you considered using `re.findall` with eg [`[\w-]+|[^\w-]`](https://regex101.com/r/vaBJH0/2/) maybe that's better fitting your needs:) But I'm not from Python, you'll know better probably!

Comment: [See this Python demo](https://tio.run/##Hc0xC8IwEAXgPb/inNKi7eIsuDorOFSF0J72IM2FuxMR/O8xOjze8vFeftvMaVsKLZnFQNA5NYEd@DNCkBqDwyORIRw5Po046QpOM5IALoFiRxOQwlgtiu7pb5VjP/LinRPUOibY3ylNIcZG/HB5ddf1Z7j92m@g/rUuCyVrqm5L@QI)

Comment: findall is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you quantify `([^a-zA-Z0-9-])+` the whole [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), it only holds the last match. You'd need to either put the quantifier inside the group `([^a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` to capture the full sequence or get each match by dropping it `([^a-zA-Z0-9-])`. But funnily `split` causes an additional empty match.

**Alternatively** use **`re.findall`** with something like [`[\w-]+|[^\w-]`](https://regex101.com/r/vaBJH0/2/) to get desired output.

- `[\w-]+` matches [one or more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) characters, that are either a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) or a hyphen.
- `|[^\w-]` OR one of its [negation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

[See this Python demo](https://tio.run/##Hc0xC8IwEAXgPb/inNKi7eIsuDorOFSF0J72IM2FuxMR/O8xOjze8vFeftvMaVsKLZnFQNA5NYEd@DNCkBqDwyORIRw5Po046QpOM5IALoFiRxOQwlgtiu7pb5VjP/LinRPUOibY3ylNIcZG/HB5ddf1Z7j92m@g/rUuCyVrqm5L@QI)

---

If you really need to use `re.split`, try[`\b` word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) without capture.

```
res = re.split(r'\b(?!-|^|$)(?<!-)|\B(?!\w)', str)
```

[Play with the pattern at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7JhWgX/2)

`\B` is the negation of `\b` and matches at any position between word characters or between non word characters, where a `\b` would not match. Applying further conditions by use of the lookarounds.

Comment: I am still not really sure why split is reacting in this way

Comment: @EXODIA Me neither, you can start a new question? My explanation would be as follows. I tried this with PHP: [`preg_split('~([^a-zA-Z0-9-])~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)`](https://tio.run/##HY1PC4IwHEDvfopfEKjgoo7RH5OSEgyGGUFRY@jQgbqxzQ4d/OrLOrzb4z1ZS2vXIT5hx5lqo2AD7o0BVSMGkqrjhsFFNL3hotMTyGvGFbCW8gbxEriGYnSZ0jv@d7VoZoVo3ZXjvKkiZd9KTypWES0bbjx38B4vij4Rus/REj39wQ3g9w0ALQLAWXwkF5wmOTnEaXIm@wjn1yz2/bEXbq39Ag) which also results in an extra match. It happens as soon as two split sequences are next to each other. Also try with `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`. After each letter there would be an empty str.

Comment: I think the reason is, that by use of parentheses you can optionally output the split sequence. But because you're using a `split` function there will always be one split. As soon, as you get two split sequences besides each other, there will be an addtional split between them because of using `split` function.